# Problema ao fazer um request do tipo POST

Tags: java, api, rest

Olá, estou tentando fazer um request do tipo POST com Bearer token para um endpoint. Quando realizo essa requisição pelo postamn ele retorna normalmente, mas quando é realizado pelo método que criei usando api RestTemplate do java, ele dá o erro "401 Unauthorized". Segue o código abaixo:

```
public <T> T sendRequestWithBody(String urlRequest, String jsonValue){
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.set("Autorization", "Bearer  ".concat(getToken()));

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("query", jsonValue);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(), header);

       ParameterizedTypeReference<T> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {
       };

       ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlRequest, HttpMethod.POST, request, typeRef);

        return response.getBody();
    }
```

Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda? Obs: Fiz um método bem parecido com esse para pegar o token, e ele gera normalmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o erro é `401` ele tem a ver com seu header.

Monte o cabeçalho da requisição (headers) dessa maneira:

```
String accessToken = "Bearer " + getToken();
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add("Authorization", accessToken);
headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
```

Da forma que você está montando o json que está enviando, ele ficará assim:
`{'query': 'valor na variavel json value'}`
É esse mesmo o objetivo?

Geralmente utilizo o método `postForObject` ao invés de `exchange`. Acho mais simples.

Da [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-client-access):

`exchange`

> More generalized (and less opinionated) version of the preceding
> methods that provides extra flexibility when needed. It accepts a
> RequestEntity (including HTTP method, URL, headers, and body as input)
> and returns a ResponseEntity.
>
> These methods allow the use of ParameterizedTypeReference instead of
> Class to specify a response type with generics.

`postForObject`

> Creates a new resource by using POST and returns the representation
> from the response.

Vou colocar um exemplo completo aqui usando `postForObject`. Realizei um teste aqui e está funcionando.

```
    @RequestMapping("/teste")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testeRestClient() {

        String accessToken = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZWxsZXJJZCI6Niwic2NvcGUiOlsibWFy"; 
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        headers.add("Authorization", accessToken);
        headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());

        String urlRequest = "http://localhost:8080/books";
        
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", "titulo 2");
        jsonObject.put("author", "fulano de tal");
        jsonObject.put("price", new BigDecimal(30));
        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), headers);
        String result = restTemplate.postForObject(urlRequest, entity, String.class);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Olá. Deu certo dessa forma!